# Method of singleton class is thread safe or not with shared resource being used inside method?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

I have a Singleton class which has a method to get the lock, all threads call that method before proceeding with the method execution. and the lock is acquired based on the value against a Redis key **(if the value is 1 lock acquired, else not)**.

Don't I need to synchronize this method?

```
public long getLock(Item item) {
    ValueOperations ops = template.opsForValue();
    return ops.increment(item.getKey());
}
```

Whatever the answer is (Yes/No), please describe the reason.

Comment: I think the answer depends on what's in the `ops.increment` method.

Comment: It is Redis INCR operation https://redis.io/commands/incr, do you mean if it is an atomic operation getLock(Item item) method is safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method looks thread safe because of the redis increment operation.

Redis increment operation is atomic in nature and redis operations are being performed one at a time.